# ExtJS - Creating hyperlinks with a function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, wcf, extjs

I'm trying to build an edit column, but my routine isn't quite right for some reason. My value of "store" is not returning anything like I thought it would.

Any thoughts?

```
    function editLinkRenderer(value, metadata, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
    if (store == V2020.ServiceStore)
        return '<a href="javascript:editServices(' + value + ')">Edit</a>';
    else if (store == V2020.PriceStore)
        return '<a href="javascript:editPrice(' + value + ')">Edit</a>';
    else if (store == V2020.PromoStore)
        return '<a href="javascript:editPromo(' + value + ')">Edit</a>';
    return "Edit";
}
```

I'm using it in my gridpanel like so:

```
{ header: "Edit", width: 60, dataIndex: 'serviceID', sortable: false, renderer: editLinkRenderer },
```

Comment: I don't see any mistake in your code, the only possibility I can see is the `store == V2020.ServiceStore` to be true the two object has to be the same instance. using firebug does the store seems to be ok?

Comment: How is this function being called?  If this is a listener to something like an EditorGridPanel, you should know which store it's being called from.  Offhand, I can't tell which event would trigger this function.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using an [ActionColumn](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.grid.ActionColumn). That way you can do this:

```
var items = [ ... ]; // existing items
if (store.constructEditColumn) {
  items.push(store.constructEditColumn());
}
```

Where your `constructEditColumn` might look like this:

```
...

constructEditColumn: function() {
  return {
    xtype: 'actioncolumn',
    items: {
      text: 'Edit',
      handler: function() {
        // do stuff
      },
      scope: this
    }
  }
},
...
```

Barring that, I'd be suspicious of doing equality on the stores. Are the two params before `store` ints? Can you breakpoint and take a look at whether the `record.store` property is what you expect? Old version of Ext, perhaps, with a different signature to the renderer?

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate you taking a look, but I figured out the issue.

I had two V2020.ServiceStore defined by mistake and the latter one was mucking everything up.